# Unity2D Character stutter with basic movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following character movement: If you press Space, character goes up. If you don't press Space, character goes down.

I'm trying to add some boundaries so the character can't go outside the zone. However i'm having some stuttering when the character reaches the top. What is the correct way to do this?

I've already tried adding the logic on FixedUpdate, doesn't fix it.

This is what's happening: [image: GIF of my problem]

This is the code:

```
private bool aboveSky = false;
private bool belowGround = false;

private float sky = -8f;
private float ground = -16.5f;

void Update () {
    float positionY = transform.position.y;
    aboveSky = positionY >= sky;
    belowGround = positionY <= ground;
    
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && !aboveSky)
    {
        transform.Translate(-10f * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f);
    }
    else if (!belowGround)
    {
        transform.Translate(10f * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is jittering as you are approaching your threshold point, then continually exceeding it, then dropping and looping. Try to clamp the value after setting it. Clamping the value should smooth it out.

```
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        transform.Translate(0f, 10f * Time.deltaTime, 0f);
    }
    else
    {
        transform.Translate(0f, -10f * Time.deltaTime, 0f);
    }

    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y, ground, sky));
}
```

I am also not sure how you are moving in the y-axis when you are using the x component of the `Translate` method. Is your object rotate in an odd way? As I am not sure about the orientation of your object, you might need to tweak the above snippet to meet your needs.

Comment: I believe it's because Its a default triangle sprite rotated 90degrees in the z axis, and I'm guessing its moving in the local x-y axis instead of global axis?

Comment: @SwamiGallardo That would do it yep. As your X has become your Y, you can tweak the code to work, but I would recommend getting a new asset without rotation, or to use `transform.up` to get relative upward positions.

Comment: By the way, Mathf.Clamp was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

`transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y, ground, sky));
 `

Comment: I will try those, thank you very much for your help.